# OneLogin php saml - Issues with SAML response

Tags: xsd, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, xsd-validation, onelogin

I have integrated OneLogin using php-saml to connect to our idp service. In our staging environment, everything works fine with the setup we are using.

I am running into an issue using those same files on our production environment however.

The problem is that the SAML response isn't correctly being validated with the `saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd` schema and is throwing errors about it.

```
$settingsInfo = array(
    'strict' => true,
    'debug' => false,
    'sp' => array(
        'entityId' => 'website',
        'assertionConsumerService' => array(
            'url' => "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
            'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
        ) ,
        'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',
        'x509cert' => file_get_contents('tool-sso.pem', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) ,
        'privateKey' => file_get_contents('tool-sso.key', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) ,
    ) ,
    'idp' => array(
        'entityId' => 'https://sso.example.com',
        'singleSignOnService' => array(
            'url' => 'https://sso.example.com/idp/SSO.saml2',
            'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
        ) ,
        'singleLogoutService' => array(
            'url' => 'https://sso.example.com/idp/SSO.saml2',
            'binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
        ) ,
        'x509cert' => file_get_contents('sso.pem', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)
    ) ,
    'compress' => array(
        'requests' => true,
        'responses' => true
    ) ,
    'security' => array(
        'authnRequestsSigned' => true,
        'signatureAlgorithm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256',
    )
);
```

However, if I add the following line to the security settings, it works just fine:

`'wantXMLValidation' => false`

This makes me think that the SAML response we are getting back from idp is somehow not in the expected format as defined by the `xsd`.

Any thoughts as to what might cause the `wantXMLValidation=true` to fail? Is it due to missing/additional/incorrect data in the SAML response or could the issue be with how we are sending data?

I am trying to rule out idp as being the issue here but in order to keep our staging and production environments in sync, I want to get that `wantXMLValidation` flag set back to true.

I have tried running the response against the `Validate XML with the XSD schema` [tool](https://www.samltool.com/validate_xml.php) and it comes back as valid xml.

The specific error I am getting when XML Validation is on is as follows:

```
    Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in \\fileshare\root\resources\Classes\OneLogin\src\Saml2\Utils.php on line 135 failed to load external entity "/fileshare/root/resources/Classes/OneLogin/src/Saml2/schemas/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location '/fileshare/root/resources/Classes/OneLogin/src/Saml2/schemas/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'. Skipping the import. failed to load external entity "/fileshare/root/resources/Classes/OneLogin/src/Saml2/schemas/xenc-schema.xsd" Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location '/fileshare/root/resources/Classes/OneLogin/src/Saml2/schemas/xenc-schema.xsd'. Skipping the import. Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData' does not resolve to a(n) element declaration. Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedKey' does not resolve to a(n) element declaration. Invalid SAML Response. Not match the saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd
invalid_response

OneLogin\Saml2\Auth Object
(
    [_settings:OneLogin\Saml2\Auth:private] => OneLogin\Saml2\Settings Object
```

**Environment:**

My setup is a load balancer with 2 windows servers and a single file-share. User connects to LB, web-sever running PHP calls the onelogin PHP files from the file-share (not on the same server as the webservers). The only reason I bring this up is because I am wondering if there is something to do with how the `schemaLocations` are trying to read the `.xsd` files.

**Update:**

I may have figured this out, just not a better way to fix it.

There is a function in the OneLogin file `Utils.php` called `validateXML` which loads the schema file that it compares the SAML response with. After some trial an error, I moved the schema files directly to the web server and not the file-share. After moving them and hardcoding the location of these schema files, the issue is resolved.

```
public static function validateXML($xml, $schema, $debug = false)
    {
        assert(is_string($xml) || $xml instanceof DOMDocument);
        assert(is_string($schema));

        libxml_clear_errors();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        if ($xml instanceof DOMDocument) {
            $dom = $xml;
        } else {
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            $dom = self::loadXML($dom, $xml);
            if (!$dom) {
                return 'unloaded_xml';
            }
        }

        //$schemaFile = __DIR__ . '/schemas/' . $schema;
        $schemaFile = 'file://C:\inetpub\wwwroot\config\schemas\\'. $schema;
```

Prior to this change, the schema file would have been looking at the fileshare for this xsd.

I am not sure if this is a path issue with libXML not being able to read for a directory like this or whether its permissions etc.

I would prefer to have the schemas in the same folder as `OneLogin` and not have to refer to them from the web-server itself.

Anything stand out with my paths that I might be missing here?